# SQL Time and Attendance Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to do a similar query to this previous question: [SQL Query for time In/Out attendance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236820/sql-query-for-time-in-out-attendance/62047128#62047128)

My data is in the following format:

```
    --------------------------------
    ID_Emp| Name    |   Date
    --------------------------------
    11    |Jon     |14/05/2014 8:00
    11    |Jon     |14/05/2014 12:00
    11    |Jon     |14/05/2014 12:30
    11    |Jon     |14/05/2014 16:00
    12    |Beth    |14/05/2014 8:00
    12    |Beth    |14/05/2014 12:00
    12    |Beth    |14/05/2014 12:30
    12    |Beth    |14/05/2014 16:00
    13    |Bob     |14/05/2014 8:00
    13    |Bob     |14/05/2014 12:00
    13    |Bob     |14/05/2014 12:30
    13    |Bob     |14/05/2014 16:00
```

But would like to build a query with it in the following format:

```
    -----------------------------

    ID_Emp|Name    |Date            |TimeIn1 |TimeOut1 |TimeIn2 |TimeOut2
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    11    |Jon     |14/05/2014      |8:00    |12:00    |12:30   |16:00
    12    |Beth    |14/05/2014      |8:00    |12:00    |12:30   |16:00
    13    |Bob     |14/05/2014      |8:00    |12:00    |12:30   |16:00
```

Comment: What's the expected result if someone suddenly does a third pass on a day.

Comment: I'd rather that not be picked up if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select id_emp, name, convert(date, date),
       convert(time, max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end)) as timein1,
       convert(time, max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end)) as timein2,
       convert(time, max(case when seqnum = 3 then date end)) as timein3,
       convert(time, max(case when seqnum = 4 then date end)) as timein4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_emp, convert(date, date) order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id_emp, name, convert(date, date);
```